# Keep up doing something meaning

Tags: idiomatic-language

Someone posted a joke on social media and I want to encourage her to keep sending more. Will the followings work? Is there another phrase that's (more) idiomatic or appropriate for achieving my aim?

Keep sending jokes

Keep sending more jokes

Keep up sending jokes

Keep up sending more jokes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first and second examples work. Rather than "keep up", you might use "Keep on sending jokes." The examples with "more" are a little redundant, but still usable.
For something informal, you could say
"I like your jokes. Keep them coming!".